'Invalid filter: 'length_is' Error in Django Template – How to Fix?
I’m encountering a TemplateSyntaxError in my Django project when rendering a template. The error message I’m seeing is: TemplateSyntaxError at
/admin/dashboard/program/add/
           Invalid filter: 'length_is'
Django Version: 5.1
Python Version: 3.12.4
Error Location: This error appears in a Django template at line 22 of the fieldset.html file.

{% for line in fieldset %}
<div class="form-group{% if line.fields|length_is:'1' and line.errors %} errors{% endif %}{% if not line.has_visible_field %} hidden{% endif %}{% for field in line %}{% if field.field.name %} field-{{ field.field.name }}{% endif %}{% endfor %}">
    <div class="row">
        {% for field in line %}
        <label class="{% if not line.fields|length_is:'1' and forloop.counter != 1 %}col-auto {% else %}col-sm-3 {% endif %}text-left" for="id_{{ field.field.name }}">
            {{ field.field.label|capfirst }}
            {% if field.field.field.required %}
            <span class="text-red">* </span>
            {% endif %}
        </label>
        <div class="{% if not line.fields|length_is:'1' %} col-auto  fieldBox {% else %} col-sm-7 {% endif %}
                     {% if field.field.name %} field-{{ field.field.name }}{% endif %}">

What I Tried:
Checked for Custom Filters:
I reviewed my project and its installed packages to verify if there is a custom filter named length_is. I found that no such custom filter is defined in my project.
Verified Django Installation:
I ensured that Django is correctly installed and up-to-date with version 5.1.
Reviewed Template Code:
I carefully examined the template code that causes the error. I found that line.fields|length_is:'1' is used, but the length_is filter is not a standard Django filter.
Searched for Package Bugs:
I searched through documentation and bug reports related to django-jazzmin to see if there is any mention of the length_is filter issue, but I could not find relevant information.
What I Expected:
I expected to find either:
Documentation or a reference indicating that length_is is a standard Django filter or a filter provided by an external package.
Guidance on how to define or implement the length_is filter if it is a custom filter not included by default.
A resolution indicating that the issue might be related to a version mismatch or configuration issue that could be easily resolved.
Since I couldn’t find any useful information or documentation about this filter, I’m unsure how to proceed. Any help on defining or correctly using the length_is filter in Django templates would be greatly appreciated.

So where in the template is there a .fields|length_is:'1'?

The length_is filter has been deprecated since Django 4.2, and was finally removed in 5.1.

How to fix this?

Three options.  One, create your own template tag.  Two, do the logic in your view, and send the result in the context.  Third, of course, is to downgrade to Django 4.2 (not recommended!).

Fixed it, it's about compatibility, between django5.1 and jazzmin specially length_is. Installed version django 5.0

Don't copy the old length_is template tag from Django 5.0.x. If this is in an upstream repository, propose the appropriate change to the project (or use the approach provided here: https://github.com/farridav/django-jazzmin/issues/593#issuecomment-2288096357
Update: The specific fix has been merged in: https://github.com/farridav/django-jazzmin/pull/519)
This template filter was removed in Django 5.1. The reason for its removal can be found in the Django 5.1 release notes and is explained in the source code:
    warnings.warn(
        "The length_is template filter is deprecated in favor of the length template "
        "filter and the == operator within an {% if %} tag.",
        RemovedInDjango51Warning,
    )

See the source code for more details.
Recommended Update
Instead of using length_is:'n', update your template to use the length filter with the == operator:
Old syntax:
{% if value|length_is:'n' %}...{% endif %}

New syntax:
{% if value|length == n %}...{% endif %}

You can also handle alternative outputs like this:
{% if value|length == n %}True{% else %}False{% endif %}

This approach aligns with Django's recommended practices and ensures your templates are forward-compatible.

This can be resolved simply by replacing all the "length_is" in fild with "length =="
this worked for me .

Okay, thanks for your comment.

i did the same thing  as already answered by https://stackoverflow.com/users/4934984/tushortz
with slight changes . worked for me.
I faced the same issue with Django jazzmin when i upgraded my Django version. Here is how to fix it.
Step 1 - Create a customtags.py file in one of your apps folder
myapp/templatetags/customtags.py
Step 2 - Paste the length_is code from the Django repo on GitHub
Step 3 - Add the relative path to your customtags file to your settings file. Under the TEMPLATES section.
--------------      my code      --------------
    # import warnings

    # from django.utils.deprecation import RemovedInDjango51Warning


    from django.contrib.admin import register

    from django import template

    register = template.Library()

    @register.filter(is_safe=False)
    def length_is(value, arg):
        """Return a boolean of whether the value's length is the argument."""
        
        try:
            return len(value) == int(arg)
        except (ValueError, TypeError):
            return ""



I faced the same issue with Django jazzmin when i upgraded my Django version. Here is how to fix it.
Step 1 - Create a customtags.py file in one of your apps folder
myapp/templatetags/customtags.py

Step 2 - Paste the length_is code from the Django repo on GitHub
Step 3 - Add the relative path to your customtags file to your settings file. Under the TEMPLATES section.
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [BASE_DIR / "templates"],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
                "django.template.context_processors.media",
                "django.template.context_processors.i18n",
            ],
            "builtins": ["myapp.templatetags.customtags"], # <- HERE
        },
    },
]

Source: How to fix removed template tags in Django admin

Consider what you are copying and pasting. Read the deprecation notice and implement the proposed change instead of re-adding deprecated functionality.

This is to fix issues with packages that still implements the old filter @mbeacom
